# Should changes to the value of a SELECT control made in code trigger the onChange Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using the following code to watch for changes to a given SELECT element.

```
  someSelectElement.change(function () { alert('change made'); });
```

And it works peachy when I change the value the selected item through the UI.

However, It doesn't seem to trigger the event if the value is changed via a script. For example, the following code executed in the debugging console **changes the selected item**, but **does NOT fire the event**.

```
$('#someSelectElement').val('NewValue')
```

I know it seems unusual to need to detect changes made to the control by the other code, and if it was my code I'd just manually trigger the event and call it a day. The trouble is, I am writing a jQuery plug-in that needs to do something when the value of a watched control changes whether it be through user intervention or some client-side script that the user of my plug-in is running.

I'm assuming the behavior of not triggering events in this situation is by design. If not, please speak up and let me know what I'm doing wrong. If so, is there a workaround where I can watch for changes made to the value of a SELECT element regardless of whether they were user or code initiated?

Comment: Let me know if you end up using my craziness below and whether or not it actually worked in a real-world scenario. I'd be interested in your results :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code-driven changes to element values don't trigger native events. You can always trigger them yourself, of course, via the jQuery ".trigger()" method.

The Mozilla browsers have long had a "watch" feature, but that's not supported by other platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it is helpful. However, as I mentioned the code that would be changing the value of the control would be from a third party who is using my code as a library. So I can't really insert a trigger into code that will be written by someone else in the future. +1 for the partial help though.

Comment: The classic hack in this case is to start up an interval timer and watch your element from there.  It sounds kind-of gross, but if all it does is check an element value every 100 milliseconds or so, it really won't be crippling the browser. Now, if you have 73 of these fields that might get a little problematic, but for one or two it would be unnoticeable to a user.

Answer (score 3):

Okay - so I *might* have a better solution to this than the interval timer solution.

Also note that this is a **MUCH** larger hack and the following is simply proof of concept and by no means is production-ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function change(){
        $('#test option[value=3]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }

    // run it before changing it
    alert('first go');
    change();

    var tmp = String(change).replace(/function change\(\){/, '');
    tmp = tmp.replace('}', '');
    tmp += 'alert(\'it changed\');';

    change = function() { eval(tmp); };

    // try it again - should get the second alert this time
    alert('second go (post mod)');
    change();
});
```

[See the sample here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/B4uCR/)

Essentially, what I'm doing is:

1. Convert the function to a string
2. Replace the bounding function constructs
3. Add whatever functionality I want to inject
4. Reassign the modified function to the original function

Seems to work, but might not in the real world :)